# Conditional Regular Expression IF Then Else?

Tags: c#, regex

I need help writing an expression to extract each word of a line of text, which can arrive in three different patterns.

Here is an example of the three patterns:

Name:  JAMES, 1ST LT LABRON

Name:  KNOTS, PFC DON

Name:  BUILDER, BOB

There is a First Name, Last Name and up to two titles. Each needing to be pulled out if they exist. Writing an expression for each text scenario is easy enough but how do I make that conditional in one expression?

Comment: Why does it need to be in one expression?

Comment: Im new so maybe not explaining well.  Im parsing the body text of email through an application and can specify the regular expression. not sure if I can specify more than one.

Comment: You should be able to parse the body text with as many regexes as you need, as long as you do them one at a time. Can you show what your code looks like?

Comment: I'm not saying you couldn't write one regex looking for 0-2 of your list of titles, but generally simpler code is easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: ((\w+)\:\s+(\w+)\,\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+))  This is the expression that I have to include all four possible words, which is the most that will ever come through on the Name: line.  But I dont know how to make it conditional for the two title words in the middle.  For... Name: JAMES, 1ST LT LABRON

Comment: I am by no means a regex expert, and I don't have anything here to validate this, but if you're looking for `Name:` then look for that, then look for titles, then the first name: you're going to need a list of titles, though, that doesn't intersect with first names: something like `Name:\s+([1st|Lt|PFC|King|Gen|etc]){0,2}\s+(\w)`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this approach using **Groups**:

```
(?<last_name>\w+),\s(?:(?<title_one>\w+)\s)?(?:(?<title_two>\w+)\s)?(?<first_name>\w+)$
```

[image]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uArP6a/6) - to demonstrate how the groups will work - see Match Information on the right.

```
(?<last_name>\w+)            start with the last name, capture all word characters          
,\s                          match comma and following whitespace
(?:(?<title_one>\w+)\s)?     first title non-capturing group - matching chars and following whitespace - is optional
(?:(?<title_two>\w+)\s)?     second title non-capturing group - matching chars and following whitespace - is optional
(?<first_name>\w+)           first name group - matching chars and is NOT optional
$                            end of line
```

You can then easily retrieve different parts of the entry via the individual groups and combine as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe this expression might be close to what you have in mind,

```
^Name:\s*([^,]*?)\s*,\s*(.*\s)?(\S*)$
```

not sure though.

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"^Name:\s*([^,]*?)\s*,\s*(.*\s)?(\S*)$";
        string input = @"Name: JAMES, 1ST LT LABRON
Name: KNOTS, PFC DON
Name: BUILDER , BOB
Name: JAMES, 1ST LT O'CONNOR
Name: KNOTS, PFC Renée
Name: BUILDER , Chloé";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
> explained on the top right panel of
> [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nYA1aF/1/). If you'd like, you
> can also watch in [this
> link](https://regex101.com/r/nYA1aF/1/debugger), how it would match
> against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would try this:

```
^(\w*\w*),\s+(\w*\w*)\s+(\w*\w*)\s+(\w*\w*)\s*$|^(\w*\w*),\s+(\w*\w*)\s+(\w*\w*)$|^(\w*\w*),\s+(\w*\w*)$
```

Then when you check the results: If you fot 4 matches, you got:
JAMES, 1ST LT LABRON
If you got 3 matches, you got:
KNOTS, PFC DON
And finally, if you only got two matches, you got:
BUILDER, BOB